# Улучшение страницы справки «Как удалить свою учетную запись?»

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка

Заголовок: How do I delete my account?
Ссылка на текущую версию на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

---

*User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.*

You should see a [Delete Profile](/users/delete/current) option on your user profile by clicking the *Edit Profile & Settings* link at the top of your profile page:

[image: self-delete from profile]

Visit that page and read through the information there. Once you've done so,
 check the box to indicate that you understand the implications of deleting your profile and then click the Delete Profile button.

If you have never posted or voted more than once on your profile, it will be *immediately* deleted. Otherwise, you will be scheduled for deletion. During that time, you can cancel the deletion request by visiting your profile and clicking the cancel link in the banner at the top. Otherwise, it will be deleted after 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Заголовок: Как удалить свою учетную запись?
Ссылка на текущую версию на русском: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

---

*Удаление пользователя необратимо! После рассмотрения запроса ваши голоса будут отозваны, а все ваши сообщения станут анонимными.*

**Если с вашей учетной записи было отправлено не более одного голоса или сообщения:**

Рядом со ссылкой «редактировать» будет находиться ссылка «удалить»:

[image: картинка]

---

**Если вы *уже* голосовали или отправляли сообщения, свяжитесь с компанией Stack Exchange:**

Откройте [анкету для связи с нами](/contact) и выберите пункт «я хочу удалить свой профиль пользователя». После этого компания вышлет вам дальнейшие инструкции.